# Sortdialog Box VBA

Tags: vba, excel

All I have the below code which selects a variable range and displays the user with a sort dialog box. Which enables the user to sort the data.

The issue I face is that the sort dialog appears with the "My data has headers" box unticked. I need to force this to always be selected.

Any advice of how to ensure this is ticked would be much appreciated.

```
OtherExp.Range("B3:CE" & lastrow).Select

On Error Resume Next
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSort).Show
If Err.Number = 1004 Then
    MsgBox "Place the cursor in the area to be sorted"
End If
Err.Clear
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
ActiveSheet.Sort.Header = xlYes
Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSort).Show
```

Comment: This is interesting. But with me (German Excel) `arg9:=xlNo` still leaves the checkbox.

Comment: @Vityata I should have tested first. It didn't pick up the argument for some reason. So switched to the above.

Comment: @vityata TBH It seems to remember the last setting you put in. I don't know if this is preserved between sessions, but can one not simply tick this box and it remain in place until unchecked?

Answer (score 1):

You can perform some workaround and force the `.Header` in the sort, using `.Header = xlYes`:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim mySort As Sort
    Dim myRng As Range: Set myRng = Range("A1:B3")
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Worksheets(1)

    If Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSort).Show Then
        Set mySort = ws.Sort
        mySort.SetRange myRng
        mySort.Header = xlYes
        mySort.SortMethod = xlPinYin
        mySort.Apply
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for providing the solution above - This also works well!